# How can I save data from external JSON to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

How can I save data from external JSON to HTML?

I have a website http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/USD?format=json and I need to save only `rates.mid` from this query and multiply it by PLN value in html file. Could anybody help me?

Daniel.

Comment: Do you have jQuery?

Comment: Of course. jQuery 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i don't know if you have jQuery, i took the xhr example of: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhr-responsetype-json

We basically add the function `getJSON` which allows us to load the JSON File.

With `data.rates[0].mid` we can access the `mid` value (rates is an array).

```js
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
 var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
  ? new XMLHttpRequest()
  : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 xhr.open('get', url, true);
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var status;
  var data;
  // https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
   status = xhr.status;
   if (status == 200) {
    data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    successHandler && successHandler(data);
   } else {
    errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
   }
  }
 };
 xhr.send();
};

getJSON('https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/USD?format=json', function(data) {
 alert(data.rates[0].mid);
}, function(status) {
 alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

With jQuery this will work:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/USD?format=json',
function(data){
    alert(data.rates[0].mid);
},function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I added the jQuery example ;)

Comment: I modified code to something like [this](http://codepen.io/clamsioPL/pen/bqjEPW) and it's working!

Thank you so much, again :)

Comment: Since you have jQuery you can also use the jQuery selectors: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpBNLq

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" > </script>

<script>

    $(function() {


   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

people.json

{
   "person": [
       {
           "firstName": "Clark",
           "lastName": "Kent",
           "job": "Reporter",
           "roll": 20
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Bruce",
           "lastName": "Wayne",
           "job": "Playboy",
           "roll": 30
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Peter",
           "lastName": "Parker",
           "job": "Photographer",
           "roll": 40
       }
   ]
}

Hope i will help you :)
```

Comment: Don't forget to explain why this will help, either with inline comments in the code itself or with a little brief explanation either before or after the code; this way people won't contend that this is a "code-only" answer.